# How can I install a module in Plone 4.0.5?

Tags: html, website-design, import, plone

I have an existing website that is old and html. I'd like to import it into Plone, and make it "Future Proof" thanks to Plone.

I found on the Plone website which modules could help me with it: FunnelWeb, mr.importer and Collective.xdv. I downloaded and extracted all of them, but now I don't know what I should do with these Folders... It's not on the website and neither in the ReadMe File...

I'm sorry if it might be a silly question for most of you, but it's too hard for me... ;-)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This presumes you've installed plone already.

The instructions for FunnelWeb [say](http://plone.org/products/funnelweb)

> The simplest way to install is via a
>   buildout recipe (see zc.buildout)

```
[buildout]
parts += funnelweb

[funnelweb]
recipe = funnelweb
crawler-url=http://www.whitehouse.gov
ploneupload-target=http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/Plone

$> buildout init
$> bin/buildout
```

For mr.importer, now [charm](http://plone.org/products/charm) it says:

```
$ bin/plone run bin/charm /path/to/files
```

For collective.xdv the instructions are here: http://plone.org/products/collective.xdv/documentation/reference-manual/theming/adding-xdv-to-your-plone-instance

Comment: What does it mean? How do I enter the "recipe"? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to Plone, and new to CMS...

Comment: The best thing to do is work your way through the tutorial: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/managing-projects-with-buildout